# Updating open orders from a price list within a range of dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

**Setup**

I've set up an example on [rextester](http://rextester.com/ZTCECJ51955) and [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=fa1966bf9efdd5093f56f12cbc5c9886).

**Scenario**

*Price list*: Its the products price list, one Products can have more than one active price, even a future price.

```
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
| product | price | date_price |  base  | active |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
|   0125  |    90 | 01.01.2017 |  1200  |    0   |
|   0125  |   100 | 25.01.2017 |  1000  |    1   |
|   0125  |   110 | 27.02.2017 |   500  |    1   |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
|   1200  |   140 | 01.01.2017 |  2000  |    0   |
|   1200  |   150 | 01.02.2017 |  1500  |    1   |
|   1200  |   160 | 27.02.2017 |  1000  |    1   |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
```

*Orders* Pending orders have a price and an order's date

```
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
| product | order_date | price |  base  |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
|   0125  | 19.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 20.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 21.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 22.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 23.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 28.02.2017 |  110  |   500  |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
|   1200  | 19.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 20.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 21.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 22.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 23.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 28.02.2017 |  160  |  1000  |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Every time we add a new price in the list, we must update affected rows of pending orders.

For example if we add:

```
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
| product | price | date_price |  base  | active |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
|   0125  |   105 | 21.02.2017 |  1300  |    1   |
|   1200  |   155 | 21.02.2017 |  1400  |    1   |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+--------+
```

The new price list must be:

```
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
| product | order_date | price |  base  |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
|   0125  | 19.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 20.02.2017 |  100  |  1000  |
|   0125  | 21.02.2017 |  105  |  1300  | *
|   0125  | 22.02.2017 |  105  |  1300  | * Affected rows
|   0125  | 23.02.2017 |  105  |  1300  | *
|   0125  | 28.02.2017 |  110  |   500  | 
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
|   1200  | 19.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 20.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  |
|   1200  | 21.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  | *
|   1200  | 22.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  | * Affectd rows between 21.02.2017 and 27.02.2017
|   1200  | 23.02.2017 |  150  |  1500  | *
|   1200  | 28.02.2017 |  160  |  1000  |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
```

I would like to update affected records using a single query.

Due there is another price that starts at 27.02.2017, orders of 28.02.2017 are not affected by the inserted price.

**Actual process**

By now, I use a subquery that search for the first date that matches in the prices list table, but now I need to update `base` field too. (And two or three more fields) and I'd like to avoid use two or more subqueries.

```
update @orders
set    price = (select   top 1 pl.price
                from     @price_list pl
                where    pl.product = o.product
                and      pl.date_price <= o.order_date
                and      active = 1
                order by pl.date_price desc),
       base  = (select   top 1 pl.base
                from     @price_list pl
                where    pl.product = o.product
                and      pl.date_price <= o.order_date
                and      active = 1
                order by pl.date_price desc)
from   @orders o
where  o.product in ('0125', '1200');  --<<< select distinct product from inserted
```

Please, feel free to correct my text, I know my english grammar isn't  good enough.

Comment: Does your 'Actual Process' do what you want, but you just don't want the multiple sub-queries?  That's why I offered CROSS APPLY (deleted answer now) as a possible solution.  The CROSS APPLY allows you to 'join' against the sub-query part as a table and pull whatever columns you need.

Comment: By now I only update the price, but there are new requirements and I don't want to use multiples subqueries if possible.,

Comment: so, why can't you use CROSS APPLY and SET o.Price = ca.Price, o.Base = ca.Base, o.AnyOtherColumn = ca.AnyOtherColumn?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used you dbfiddler code in the following solution that uses [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
declare @price_list table(product varchar(20), price int, date_price datetime, base int, active tinyint);
insert into @price_list values
('0125',  90, '2017-01-01', 1200, 0), 
('0125', 100, '2017-01-25', 1000, 1), 
('0125', 110, '2017-02-27', 500,  1),
('1200', 140, '2017-01-01', 2000, 0), 
('1200', 150, '2017-02-01', 1500, 1), 
('1200', 160, '2017-02-27', 1000, 1);

declare @orders table(product varchar(20), order_date datetime, price int, base int);
insert into @orders values
('0125', '2017-02-19', 100, 1000), 
('0125', '2017-02-20', 100, 1000),
('0125', '2017-02-21', 100, 1000), 
('0125', '2017-02-22', 100, 1000),
('0125', '2017-02-23', 100, 1000), 
('0125', '2017-02-28', 110,  500),
('1200', '2017-02-19', 150, 1500), 
('1200', '2017-02-20', 150, 1500),
('1200', '2017-02-21', 150, 1500), 
('1200', '2017-02-22', 150, 1500),
('1200', '2017-02-23', 150, 1500), 
('1200', '2017-02-28', 160, 1000);



declare @new_date_price datetime = '2017-02-21';


-- add a new price to the list
--
insert into @price_list values ('0125', 105, @new_date_price - 1, 1300, 1);
insert into @price_list values ('1200', 155, @new_date_price - 1, 1400, 1);


-- update orders price and base, according products price list date price
--
-- I'd like to avoid use 2 (or more) subqueries
--
UPDATE o
SET o.Price = ca.price
    ,o.base = ca.base
FROM @Orders o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 pl.price AS price
        ,pl.base AS base
    FROM @Price_List pl
    WHERE pl.product = o.product
        AND pl.date_price <= o.order_date
        AND active = 1
    ORDER BY pl.date_price DESC
    ) ca
WHERE o.product IN (
        '0125'
        ,'1200'
        );--<<< select distinct product from inserted
-- final result
--
select * from @price_list order by product, date_price;
select * from @orders order by product, order_date;
```

Comment: Ok, let me chek it in my db, but it looks so good. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm testing on my staging server, it works well, but by now all orders are updated. Because it will run on a trigger, do you think it would be possible to upgrade only orders that are affected by the new price list?

Comment: By new price list I mean using `select price, base, date_price from inserted`

Comment: Well - that 'sounds' reasonable - I can't immediately think of any reason that would not work...  I would certainly 'test' that in a non-production environment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to thank @ScottHodgin for his work to solve my question.

Although his answer correctly solved the problem, it updates all active orders for a particular product. And I wanted to find a solution that updates only orders affected by new price list date.

Since this procedure is executed within a trigger, I need to generate a list of date intervals to compare with the date of the orders.

I'm adding a day to 'next_date' if there is no next PriceList record, just to compare with `<=`.

```
SELECT product, price, date_price, base, active,
       (SELECT TOP 1     pl.date_price
               FROM      PriceList pl
               WHERE     pl.product = i.product
               AND       pl.date_price > i.date_price
               AND       pl.active > 0
               ORDER BY  pl.date_price ASC) next_date
FROM inserted i
```

Once solved the problem of the date range, I only need to update orders within this range.

```
WITH PList AS
(
SELECT product, price, date_price, base, active,
       (SELECT TOP 1     pl.date_price
               FROM      PriceList pl
               WHERE     pl.product = i.product
               AND       pl.date_price > i.date_price
               AND       pl.active > 0
               ORDER BY  pl.date_price ASC) next_date
FROM inserted i
)
UPDATE     Orders
SET        price = PList.price,
           base  = PList.base,
           [status] = 'Updated'
FROM       Orders o
INNER JOIN Plist
ON         Plist.product = o.product 
AND        o.order_date >= Plist.date_price
AND        o.order_date < COALESCE(Plist.next_date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Plist.next_date);
```

After inserting two records:

```
DECLARE @new_date_price datetime = '2017-02-21';

INSERT INTO PriceList VALUES 
('0125', 105, @new_date_price, 1300, 2),
('1200', 155, @new_date_price, 1400, 2);
```

This is the final result:

```
|product|order_date  |price|base|status |
|:------|:-----------|----:|---:|:------|
|0125   |Feb 19 2017 |  100|1000|       |
|0125   |Feb 20 2017 |  100|1000|       |
|0125   |Feb 21 2017 |  105|1300|Updated|
|0125   |Feb 22 2017 |  105|1300|Updated|
|0125   |Feb 23 2017 |  105|1300|Updated|
|0125   |Feb 28 2017 |  110| 500|       |
|1200   |Feb 19 2017 |  150|1500|       |
|1200   |Feb 20 2017 |  150|1500|       |
|1200   |Feb 21 2017 |  155|1400|Updated|
|1200   |Feb 22 2017 |  155|1400|Updated|
|1200   |Feb 23 2017 |  155|1400|Updated|
|1200   |Feb 28 2017 |  160|1000|       |
```

If someone are interested, I've setup a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=ad6c42df313b8511e9033574eed1eafe) example.